# Schrödinger equation with time dependent Hamiltonian

Tags: finite-element, time-integration, fenics, quantum-mechanics

I need to solve the Schrödinger equation with a time dependent Hamiltonian

$$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi =  \left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 +\frac{1}{2} k(t)(x^2+y^2) + V(r)\right]\Psi $$

Can anybody recommend me an efficient numerical method or software package for solving the problem.

**EDIT:**
This is a suitable form of the equation for numerically solving(which we discussed in the one of the below answers with [@davidhigh](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/14942/davidhigh)). 
\begin{align*}
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u_{\ell}(r,t) = \Bigg(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{2r^2} +  V(r)\Bigg)u_{\ell}(r,t)\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \nonumber\\  + \frac{2}{3}k(t)r^2 \sum_{\ell' = {max}(\ell-2,0)}^{{min}(\ell+2,L_{{max}})} \Bigg(\delta_{\ell,\ell'} - \sqrt{ \frac{4\pi}{5}} \alpha(\ell, \ell') \Bigg) u_{\ell'}(r,t)
\end{align*}
where the coefficient $\alpha(\ell, \ell')$ is given by
\begin{align*}
 \alpha(\ell, \ell') = \int Y^*_{\ell0}(\Omega)Y_{20}(\Omega)Y_{\ell'0}(\Omega) d\Omega
\end{align*}

which the integral can be solved by Wigner-3j coefficients (see  [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHarmonic.html) ).

Can anyone suggest an efficient numerically method for solving the equation?

Comment: Is using Mathematica an option?

Comment: Due to type of potential, I don't think Mathematica is an appropriate method. The potential is kind of central potential like Yukawa and Lennard Jones.

Comment: Can you add what `k(t)` and `V(r)` look like?

Comment: For example, Yukawa potiential 
$V(r) = -V_0  \frac{e^{-\alpha r}}{r}$    and  $k(t) = k_0 - F_0 \cos(\omega t)$

Comment: Could you provide more information regarding the number of particles you wish to use, domain, dimensions, etc?

Comment: We have two particles in 3D and the equation is relative equation in center of mass coordinates between particles. In center of mass equation we don't have $V(r)$ and one can solve it analytically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to try it on your own. Do an expansion of your wavefunction in terms of spherical harmonics,

$$
\psi(\mathbf r) \ = \ \sum_{\ell} R_\ell(r,t) \, Y_{\ell 0} (\theta,\phi)\,.
$$

Note that I've set the index $m$ in $Y_{\ell m}$ to zero, in order to account for the symmetry of your Hamiltonian with respect to rotations around the $x-y$ plane. This makes your problem essentially two-dimensional. You can also write the spherical harmonic in terms of Legendre polynomials,
$$
Y_{\ell0}(\theta,\varphi) = \sqrt{\frac{2\ell+1}{4\pi}} P_{\ell}(\cos\theta).
$$

Insertion into your Schrödinger equation and project on the spherical hamonics, and you'll end up with a coupled equation for the radial functions $R_l(r,t)$. Here, "coupled" means coupled in $\ell$, i.e. the function $R_\ell(r,t)$ depends on all the other quantum numbers $0\leq \ell \leq L_{\max}$. Solve that with standard finite differences, it's not that hard.

In the insertion-and-projection step above, the only problem appears in evaluating the matrix elements with $x^2+y^2$. If you write it as $r^2 Y_{10}$, it boils down to an integral over three spherical harmonics, which is related to the Clebsch-Gordan or Wigner-3j coefficients. But It's an easy one, for which analytical formulae exist (--just google for the buzzwords in the previous sentence).

If you arrived at the working formula and need further assistance, let me know.

---

EDIT: summarizing our lengthy discussion in the comment section, here is the final equation which is about to be solved numerically.

$$
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u_\ell(r,t) = \left(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{2r^2} + V(r)\right) u_\ell(r,t) \\ \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad+  \frac{2}3 \,k(t)\, r^2 \; \sum_{\ell^\prime=\max(\ell-2,0)}^{\min(\ell+2,L_\max)} \left( \delta_{\ell,\ell^\prime} - \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}5} \alpha(\ell,\ell^\prime) \right)\,u_{\ell^\prime}(r,t)
$$

Here the coefficient $\alpha(\ell,\ell^\prime)$ which you introduced is given by
$$
\alpha(\ell,\ell^\prime) \ = \ \int Y^\ast_{\ell 0}(\Omega) Y_{20}(\Omega) Y_{\ell^\prime 0}(\Omega)\ d\Omega
$$
(you can also express that more in standard terms such as Wigner3j symbols, see e.g. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHarmonic.html)).

Note the restriction in the summation indices which come from the fact that $0\leq \ell^\prime \leq L_\max$ (where $L_\max$ is the maximum angular quantum number chosen in the numerical representation).

Comment: I didn't completely catch your mean.As your mentioned, I inserted the expansion into the equation.\begin{align*}\sum_{\ell}\Big[ \frac{1}{R_{\ell}} \frac{d}{dr}(r^2 \frac{dR_{\ell}}{dr})-\frac{2mr^2}{\hbar^2}\big(\frac{1}{2}k(t)(x^2 + y^2)+V(r) \big)+\nonumber\\ \frac{2mr^2}{\hbar}\frac{1}{R_{\ell}} \frac{\partial R_{\ell}}{\partial t}\Big]+\sum_{\ell} \frac{1}{Y_{\ell 0}} \Big( \frac{1}{\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\big(\sin \theta \frac{\partial Y_{\ell 0}}{\partial \theta}\big) \Big)=0.\end{align*}we have two terms separated.Should I solve numerically the first term?

Comment: You project out the radial part, and by this you should notice that the spherical harmonics are eigenfunctions of the radial part of the Laplace operator. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_spherically_symmetric_potential), for example. But my bad, instead of $R_l(r)$ use $\frac{R_l(r)}{r}$ -- it's more appropriate for the radial part of the Laplace operator.

Comment: thanks to you. I was wondering what were your mean of $x^2 + y^2 \sim r^2Y_{20}$? Can I insert it in the equation for numerically solving?($u=rR$)
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2u(r,t)}{dr^2} - \frac{2mr^2}{\hbar^2}\Big(\frac{1}{2}k(t)r^2Y_{20} +\frac{\hbar^2 \ell (\ell +1)}{2mr^2}+V(r) \Big)u(r,t)+\frac{2imr^2}{\hbar}\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial t} = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: The idea is: express $x^2+y^2$ in terms of $r^2$ and some appropriate combination of spherical harmonics. For that, go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics), and figure out which ones to take (my attempt above is wrong)... once you have it, insert it into the Schrödinger equation ... and only thereafter, you do the projection onto spherical harmonics.

Comment: All other terms remain as in the previous link, and the only difficulty is in evaluating the $x^2+y^2$ term. For that, you get terms like $\langle Y_{lm} | Y_{20} | Y_{\bar l \bar m} \rangle$ and similar (where the inner SH comes from your expansion of $x^2+y^2$. You need to evaluate these integrals (again, there closely related to the Wigner3j symbol). In your final equation, there should be no spherical harmonics anymore, it should depend on $\ell$ and $r$ only.

Comment: I almost did it. $x^2+y^2 =\frac{2}{3}r^2-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{5}}r^2Y_{20}$, it is good idea. We have this equation in the end up:
\begin{align*}\frac{d^2u(r,t)}{dr^2} - \frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\Bigg(\frac{1}{2}k(t)\Big(\frac{2}{3}r^2-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{5}}r^2\alpha(\ell)\Big) + \frac{\hbar^2 \ell (\ell +1)}{2mr^2}+V(r) \Bigg)u(r,t)\nonumber\\ + \frac{2im}{\hbar}\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial t} = 0.\end{align*}where $\alpha(\ell)$ is function of $\ell$, which is the answer of the integral($\langle Y_{l0}|Y_{20}|Y_{l0}\rangle$). Now, we just must solve this equation numerically

Comment: ok, but there's another mistake here. The final equation should couple different $\ell$'s. You have to do the projection not on $\langle Y_{\ell 0}|$, but rather on $\langle Y_{\bar \ell 0}|$ -- note the bar here over $\ell$. (In general, you would need to project on $\langle Y_{\bar \ell \bar m}|$, but due to the properties of the Wigner-Symbol you can take $\bar m = 0$ here). In the final equation, all partial wavefunctions with $|\ell-\bar \ell| \leq 2$ should be coupled.

Comment: You right, I made big mistake. I'll do it. thanks to you for the nice discussion, I've learned many things from you.

Comment: You're welcome. If you arrived at the final equation, I'd suggest you edit it into the above question (including a short derivation). Then we can continue  with how to solve it.

Comment: It's still not completely correct. Remember that the radial wavefunction has an index $\ell$ (and inside your sum $\bar \ell$). I'd start from the beginning, insert $\sum_{\bar \ell} \frac{u_{\bar \ell}(r)}{r}Y_{\bar \ell 0}$, project on $Y^\ast_{\ell 0}$, and derive the final equation.

Comment: the final equation, I think have a form like this:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^2u(r,t)}{dr^2} - \frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\Bigg(\frac{1}{2}k(t)\Big(\frac{2}{3}r^2-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{5}}r^2\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{\ell + 2} \alpha(\ell,\ell')\Big) +\frac{\hbar^2 \ell (\ell +1)}{2mr^2}+V(r) \Bigg)u(r,t) \nonumber\\ +\frac{2im}{\hbar}\frac{\partial u(r,t)}{\partial t} = 0.
\end{align*}
where $\alpha(\ell,\ell')$ is the answer of the integral$\langle Y_{\ell'0}|Y_{20}|Y_{\ell0}\rangle$. If everything goes well, how to solve the equation? with which efficient method?

Comment: Please see my previous post, you need another index $\ell$. If you take the time to write down the derivation in your original question, we'll surely get it correct :-). Plus, we have a base for the numerical solution.

Comment: I inserted the expansion into original equation.\begin{align*}
i\sum_{\ell'}Y_{\ell'0} \frac{\partial R_{\ell'}(r,t)}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\ell'} \frac{Y_{\ell'0}}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}(r^2 \frac{dR_{\ell'}(r,t)}{dr})-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{\ell'} \frac{R_{\ell'}(r,t)}{r^2 \sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin\theta \frac{\partial Y_{\ell'0}}{\partial \theta}) \nonumber\\ + \sum_{\ell'}V(r)R_{\ell'}(r,t)Y_{\ell'0} + \frac{1}{2}k(t)(x^2+y^2)R_{\ell'}(r,t)Y_{\ell'0}
\end{align*}

Comment: Assume $x^2+y^2=\frac{2}{3}r^2-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{5}}r^2Y_{20}$ and project $Y^{*}_{\ell0} \times$ on the equation as well as $\frac{r^2}{R_{\ell'}(r,t)}$

Comment: One can rewrite:\begin{align*}
\sum_{\ell'} \frac{Y^*_{\ell 0} Y_{\ell' 0}}{R_{\ell'}} \frac{d}{dr}(r^2 \frac{dR_{\ell'}}{dr})-2r^2 \sum_{\ell'}V(r)Y^*_{\ell 0} Y_{\ell' 0}-k(t)r^2 \Big(\frac{2}{3}r^2 Y^*_{\ell 0} Y_{\ell' 0}-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{ \frac{\pi}{5}}r^2 Y^*_{\ell 0}Y_{20}Y_{\ell' 0}\Big)\nonumber\\+2ir^2 \sum_{\ell'} \frac{Y^*_{\ell 0} Y_{\ell' 0}}{R_{\ell'}} \frac{ \partial R_{ \ell'}}{\partial t}+\sum_{\ell'} \frac{Y^*_{\ell0}}{\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin\theta \frac{\partial Y_{\ell' 0}}{\partial \theta})=0
\end{align*}

Comment: In the previous equation we have two separated equation, we can equalize each one of them with a constant like $\ell'(\ell'+1)$. Also we know,$\int \int Y^{*}_{\ell 0}Y_{\ell'0} d\Omega=\delta_{\ell\ell'}$. For radial equation, one can rewrite above equation.$(R_{\ell'}(r,t) = u_{\ell'}(r,t)/r)$

Comment: \begin{align*}
\sum_{\ell'}\frac{\delta_{\ell\ell'}}{u_{\ell'}}\frac{d^2u_{\ell'}}{dr^2}-2\sum_{\ell'}\Big[\Big(V(r)+\frac{\ell'(\ell'+1)}{2r^2}\Big)\delta_{\ell\ell'}-k(t)\Big(\frac{2}{3}r^2\delta_{\ell\ell'}-\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{5}}r^2 \int \int Y^*_{\ell0}Y_{20}Y_{\ell'0} d\Omega\Big) \Big]\nonumber\\+2i\sum_{\ell'}\delta_{\ell\ell'} \frac{\partial u_{\ell'}}{\partial t}=0
\end{align*}
if the way is correct, Do we can write $\int \int Y^{*}_{\ell0}Y_{20}Y_{\ell'0} d\Omega = \sum_{\ell}^{\ell'+2} \alpha(\ell',\ell)$?

Comment: You're very close. Based on your work I edited the final equationinto my answer. I'd suggest either you ask a new question how to solve this equation numerically, or you change your question so that it asks about solving this equation.

Comment: I was wondering if I want to solve the final equation for  $\ell = 0$, we have an equation with involving $u_0 , u_1, u_2$ in last term, isn't it very complicated than the original equation to solve?

Comment: That's the deal. And solving for $\ell=0$ doesn't suffice. Instead, you need to pick a number $L_max$, and solve the coupled equations for all $0 \leq \ell \leq L_max$. Depending on the problem, $L_max$ can get quite large, say up to several hundreds. But remember, we're talking about a *three-dimensional* equation here (your equation in the original question). The rotational symmetry allowed to reduce one dimension, but the remaining equation must by two-dimensional, not one-dimensional.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61937/discussion-on-answer-by-davidhigh-schrodinger-equation-with-time-dependent-hamil).

Comment: dear @davidhigh,
I was looking for a proper numerical method for solving the equation, but I didn't find. Do you know any method for solving the equation? there is some method such as meshless method and so on.
Best,

Answer (score 2):

FEniCS users have solved this problem before, but keep in mind that FEniCS does not natively support complex numbers right now in its code. Therefore you have to make a workaround.

See: https://fenicsproject.org/qa/9209/how-to-use-complex-numbers-iterative-solvers
https://fenicsproject.org/qa/10671/mixed-function-spaces-for-complex-valued-problems-in-2016-0

Comment: I will try to solve it with your suggestion and let you know if it works.