# Time-dependent Schrodinger equation(time-dependent Hamiltonian)

Tags: numerical-analysis, finite-difference

This question was already asked [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27229/schr%c3%b6dinger-equation-with-time-dependent-hamiltonian) and this is a suitable form of the equation for numerically solving. 
\begin{align*}
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u_{\ell}(r,t) = \Bigg(-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{2r^2} +  V(r)\Bigg)u_{\ell}(r,t)\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \nonumber\\  + \frac{2}{3}k(t)r^2 \sum_{\ell' = {max}(\ell-2,0)}^{{min}(\ell+2,L_{{max}})} \Bigg(\delta_{\ell,\ell'} - \sqrt{ \frac{4\pi}{5}} \alpha(\ell, \ell') \Bigg) u_{\ell'}(r,t)
\end{align*}
where the coefficient $\alpha(\ell, \ell')$ is given by
\begin{align*}
 \alpha(\ell, \ell') = \int Y^*_{\ell0}(\Omega)Y_{20}(\Omega)Y_{\ell'0}(\Omega) d\Omega
\end{align*}

which the integral can be solved by Wigner-3j coefficients (see  [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHarmonic.html) ).

Can anyone suggest an efficient numerically method for solving the equation?

Comment: Should the last term of the equation involve $u_{\ell'}$ instead of $u_\ell$? As stated, the equations for different values of $\ell$ do not couple.